# Easeljs draw different kinds of arrows

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs

*This application is made with Easeljs, to work in HTML5 canvas.*

I want to be able to draw different kinds of arrows on the board. I tried inserting arrows as images and then making them draggable and resizable, but that made these images pretty ugly.

**To illustrate:**

[image: Field to draw on]

*Field to draw on*

[image: Dashed arrow]

[image: Wobbly arrow]

[image: Lightning arrow]

[image: Straight arrow]

[image: Curved arrow]

*Arrows to draw on the field*

The functionality should be as follows:

- Click on the button
- Draw a line
- At mouseup event: convert line into corresponding arrow
- Arrow should be draggable and resizable

How would I get this result?

Comment: Does the EaselJS package support SVG images? If so, that might be a solution to try. SVG images will scale and rotate without the ugliness I assume you experienced with a bitmap image.

Comment: It only supports SVG as an image source. You could use the Graphics vector format, and export a few arrow types from Adobe Animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fairly easily draw arrows using the Graphics API. I spent about 20 mins making this demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ukjb1g2g/2/
- http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/ukjb1g2g/3/

Code:

```
var w = startX - endX;
var h = startY - endY;
var lineLength = Math.sqrt(w*w+h*h);

arrow.graphics.clear().setStrokeStyle(3).beginStroke("#000").moveTo(0,0);
// Logic to draw to the end. This is just a straight line
arrow.lineTo(lineLength-arrowHeadSize, 0);

arrow.graphics.beginFill("#000");
arrow.graphics.drawPolyStar(lineLength, 0, arrowHeadSize, 3);

// Rotate
arrow.rotation = Math.atan2(h, w) * 180/Math.PI;
```

Drawing it straight and rotating it is the easiest way to add effects to the line. The demo I posted draws a sort of sine-wave like one of your examples. There is some more magic in there to make it the right length, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I will try creating the arrows I need using your code.